# Does the equation $3y = (\log x)^2$ define a function of $x$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions

My textbook has a question as follows

For which of the following, $y$ can be a function of $x$, ($x\in\mathbb{R}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}$)?

v) $3y = (\log x)^2$

My claim is that it is a function but my textbook says that it isn't a function and doesn't tell why.

Reasoning: For every value of $x$, there is a unique $y$ so it must be a function.

I even plotted it in my graphical  calculator and there appears to be no point where the vertical line test fails.

Graph:[image]

EDIT: A function must be defined for every point in its domain to be a function?

Comment: Yes, by the definition of domain, a function needs to be defined everywhere on its domain.

Comment: The function $\log x$ is not defined for $x\le0$, so means that $y$ cannot be a function on the whole real line.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @Marc Woops, mixed up which was supposed to be a function of which somehow.

Comment: Isn't that allowed? Of course, my function isn't one-one but I think f(x) being same for two different values of x is allowed for a function.

Comment: In order for it to be a function it has to satisfy that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for $y=f(x)$

Comment: It can be iffy.  $f: (0, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R; f(x) = (\log x)^2/3$ is a function (because it is defined on its domain) but $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R; f(x) = (\log x)^2/3$ is not because it isn't.  Mathematicians can get futzy about that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a function because $(log x)^2$ does not exist when $x\in\mathbb{Q^-}$

This means that when x is a negative number, there is no real solution.

Notice that the vertical line fails when you test it on the negative side of x.

Which is why there is no real solution to $log (-1)$ if you type it on calculator.

Comment: The Vertical Line Test states that a vertical line crosses the graph of a function *at most* once.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is $x>0$ otherwise the function is not defined. Similarly, $y\geq 0$. If these two conditions are satisfied it is a function. If we are talking for all real numbers then it is not.

Answer (score 1):

A function is defined by both its rule and its domain.

The given rule is $3y = (\log x)^2$ and the given domain is $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $\log x$ is only defined for $x > 0$, $3y = (\log x)^2$ is only defined for $x > 0$.  Since the equation is not defined for every real number, the equation $3y = (\log x)^2$ is not a function on the domain $\mathbb{R}$.